# Network graph visualizer with labels on edges as well as nodes?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

What is the best option to create a visualizer in Power BI for a Network Graph.
I need something that can connect Nodes to one another, sometimes via two or more edges, with Labels for each Edges, as well as Labels on the Nodes.

I am struggling to draw curved edges that do not overlap.
See below example picture drawn with Vega there are two links between Country 003 and 005 but the lines and labels are drawn over one another I do not know how to specify to vega to prevent curved lines overlapping.

[image]

Here is my specification containing sample data:

```html
'''

    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",

  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 50,

  "title":{"text":"Demo Report"},

"autosize": {
    "type": "pad",
    "resize": true,
    "contains": "padding"
},

  "signals": [
    {"name": "cx", "update": "width / 6"},
    {"name": "cy", "update": "height / 6"},
    {
      "name": "nodeRadius",
      "value": 15,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 50, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeCharge",
      "value": -300,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -100, "max": 10, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "linkDistance",
      "value": 50,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1}
    },
    {"name": "static", "value": true, "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}},
    {
      "description": "State variable for active node fix status.",
      "name": "fix",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout[!event.buttons], window:mouseup",
          "update": "false"
        },
        {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "fix || true"},
        {
          "events": "[symbol:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "xy()",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Graph node most recently interacted with.",
      "name": "node",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "fix === true ? item() : node"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Flag to restart Force simulation upon data changes.",
      "name": "restart",
      "value": false,
      "on": [{"events": {"signal": "fix"}, "update": "fix && fix.length"}]
    }
  ],
  "data": [

    {"name": "dataset",
    "values": [
      {"type":"Node","name":"Planet","index":0,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},
      {"type":"Node","name":"Southern Hemisphere","index":1,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},
      {"type":"Node","name":"Northern Hemisphere","index":2,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},

      {"type":"Node","name":"Country 001","index":3,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},
      {"type":"Node","name":"Country 002","index":4,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},
      {"type":"Node","name":"Country 003","index":5,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},
      {"type":"Node","name":"Country 004","index":6,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},
      {"type":"Node","name":"Country 005","index":7,"group":1,"source":-1,"target":-1,"value":-1},

      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":1,"target":0 ,"value":1},
      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":2,"target":0 ,"value":1},
      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":3,"target":1 ,"value":2},
      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":4,"target":1 ,"value":2},
      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":5,"target":2 ,"value":2},
      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":6,"target":2 ,"value":2},
      {"type":"Link","name":" ","index":-1,"group":1,"source":7,"target":2 ,"value":2},

      {"type":"Link","name":"War","index":-1,"group":1,       "source":3,"target":6 ,"value":3 },
      {"type":"Link","name":"Peace","index":-1,"group":1,     "source":5,"target":7 ,"value":4 },
      {"type":"Link","name":"Trade","index":-1,"group":1,     "source":5,"target":7 ,"value":4 },
      {"type":"Link","name":"Alliance","index":-1,"group":1,  "source":5,"target":7 ,"value":4 },
      {"type":"Link","name":"Neutral","index":-1,"group":1,   "source":6,"target":7 ,"value":4 }
    ]
    
    },



    {
      "name": "node-data",
      "source": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.type == 'Node'"
        }
      ] 
    },
    {
      "name": "link-data",
      "source": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.type == 'Link'"
        }
        
      ]
    }
 
 
 
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "node-data", "field": "group"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category20c"}
    }
  ],



  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "type": "symbol",
      "zindex": 1,
      "from": {"data": "node-data"},
      "on": [
        {
          "trigger": "fix",
          "modify": "node",
          "values": "fix === true ? {fx: node.x, fy: node.y} : {fx: fix[0], fy: fix[1]}"
        },
        {"trigger": "!fix", "modify": "node", "values": "{fx: null, fy: null}"}
      ],

      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "group"},
          "stroke": {"value": "white"}
        },
        "update": {
          "size": {"signal": "2 * nodeRadius * nodeRadius"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"},
          "tooltip": {"signal": "item"}
        }
      },



      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "force",
          "iterations": 300,
          "restart": {"signal": "restart"},
          "static": {"signal": "static"},
          "signal": "force",
          "forces": [
            {"force": "center", "x": {"signal": "cx"}, "y": {"signal": "cy"}},
            {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "nodeRadius"}},
            {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge"}},
            {
              "force": "link",
              "links": "link-data",
              "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]










    },





    {
      "type": "path",
      "name": "theLinks",
      "from": {"data": "link-data"},
      "interactive": true,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#ccc"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 3},
          "tooltip": {"signal": "item"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "require": {"signal": "force"},
          "shape": "curve",
          "sourceX": "datum.source.x",
          "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
          "targetX": "datum.target.x",
          "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "theLinks"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "signal": "((datum.bounds.x2-datum.bounds.x1)/2)+datum.bounds.x1"
          },
          "y": {
            "signal": "((datum.bounds.y2-datum.bounds.y1)/2)+datum.bounds.y1"
          },
          "text": {"signal": "datum.datum.name"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 14},
          "fontWeight":{"value":"bold"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "fill": {"value": "blue"}
        }
      }
    },
     {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "zindex": 3,
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "signal": "((datum.bounds.x2-datum.bounds.x1)/2)+datum.bounds.x1"
          },
          "y": {
            "signal": "((datum.bounds.y2-datum.bounds.y1)/2)+datum.bounds.y1"
          },
          "text": {"signal": "datum.datum.name"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 12},
          "fontWeight":{"value":"bold"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```